# React Native PanResponder

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to use the PanResponder in React Native.

Very simple -  I have 2 elements:

1. A View, which is the width of the screen and a height of 100.
2. An Animated.View, which is 50 wide, 50 high, and 25 borderRadius so it is a circle. The circle is sitting inside the main view.

I want to effectively be able to drag the circle across the screen. Could someone help me out?

Heres is my code thus far :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Animated, Dimensions, PanResponder, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';



export class MySlider extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pan: new Animated.ValueXY()
        };
    }

    _panResponder = PanResponder.create({
            // Ask to be the responder:
            onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
            onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,
            onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
            onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,

            onPanResponderGrant: (evt, gestureState) => {
                this.state.pan.setValue({x: 0, y: 0});
                return true
            },
            onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
                Animated.event([null, {dx: this.state.pan.x, dy: this.state.pan.y}])
                return true
            },
            onPanResponderTerminationRequest: (evt, gestureState) => true,
            onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {
                return true
            },
            onPanResponderTerminate: (evt, gestureState) => {
                return true
            },
            onShouldBlockNativeResponder: (evt, gestureState) => {
                return true;
            },
        });

    render() {
        let { pan } = this.state;
        let [translateX, translateY] = [pan.x, pan.y];
        const styles = StyleSheet.create({
            mover: {
                transform: [{translateX:translateX}, {translateY:5}],
                height: 50,
                width: 50,
                borderRadius: 25,
                backgroundColor: 'blue'
            },
            holder: {
                height: 100,
                width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
                backgroundColor: 'yellow'
            }
        });
        return (
            <View style={styles.holder}>
                <Animated.View style={styles.mover} {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}/>   
            </View>
            )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i changed your code a bit 
so try this

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react'
import {
  PanResponder,
  View,
  Animated,
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions
} from 'react-native'

export default class MySlider extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pan: new Animated.ValueXY()
        };
    

    this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
     onStartShouldSetPanResponder : () => true,
      onPanResponderGrant: (e, gestureState) => {
        this.setState({isAddNewSession:true})
      },
      onPanResponderMove : Animated.event([null,{ //Step 3

          dx : this.state.pan.x,
          dy : this.state.pan.y
      }]),
      onPanResponderRelease           : (e, gesture) => {  this.setState({isAddNewSessionModal:true},
        
      )
        Animated.spring(            
            this.state.pan,         
            {toValue:{x:0,y:0}}     //To default position you can delete this animated.spring() 
        ).start();
        this.setState({isAddNewSession:false})
    },
        });
}
    render() {
        let { pan } = this.state;
        let [translateX, translateY] = [pan.x, pan.y];
        const styles = StyleSheet.create({
            mover: {
                transform: [{translateX:translateX}, {translateY:translateY}],
                height: 50,
                width: 50,
                position:'absolute',
                top:0,
                borderRadius: 25,
                zIndex:20,
                backgroundColor: 'blue'
            },
            holder: {
                height: 100,
                width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
                backgroundColor: 'yellow'
            }
        });
        return (
            <View style={styles.holder}>
                <Animated.View style={styles.mover} {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}/>   
            </View>
            )
    }
}
```

let me know if its work or not...

Comment: Could you please explain what is ```isaddnewsession``` and why did you have to make the mover ```position:absolute```?

Comment: it is just for me it won't affects you i just forget to erase it...
and i added onPanResponderRelease function to reset its value to default 
i used isAddNewSession because i have to check if the circle is in the available criteria or not if it is in then i don't have to reset its value to default

Answer (score 1):

Yes that worked. I copied and pasted your class in place of my class and now it works. I can drag it in two dimensions and when I release it goes back to where it began. Thank you.

what is `this.setState({isAddNewSession:true})`, `this.setState({isAddNewSessionModal:true})` and `this.setState({isAddNewSession:false})`??

Also, when I delete the Animated.Spring, I can drag and drop the circle - but when I drag it a second time, The circle begins from the original spot. Any suggestions on how to pick up where I left off? I tried replacing dx and dy with moveX and moveY but it hasn't worked. I also tried to store the old value in a variable but it is complicated because it is an Animated value and a javascript object.